# JCheckBox added in a JTable cell is not visible

Tags: java, swing

I have added a JCheckBox in a cell of a JTable. But when the frame containing the JTable loads i can not see the JCheckBox in the JTable. Instead of the component it shows true/false values of the JCheckBox when i click on that cell.

checkbox_column=table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
checkbox_column.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(checkbox));

Also how to disable the column re positioning when you drag it in JTable?

Comment: You where asked to read the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Table" in your last posting. Again the tutorial contains a working example of how to use check boxes. Why do you think I suggested you read the tutorial. Its to learn so you don't waste our time asking questions that are covered by the documentation. Not only that you haven't even bothered to accept a single answer form all you other postings. I hope others in the forum will ingore you in the future as I plan on doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the cellEditor which handles in-place edits of the cell. The general painting of the cell is handled by the cell renderer which is set via `setCellRenderer()`

To disable column reordering, you want

```
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the data model (more specifically, the TableModel) is separate from the view.

You should set the value of the cell to a Boolean instead of setting the value to a JCheckBox.  Then make sure your TableModel's getColumnClass() method returns Boolean for column 4.  There are different ways of doing this, but [creating a custom TableModel](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and implemeting the getColumnClass() method is one way.

The DefaultCellRenderer/DefaultCellEditor will show a checkbox for Boolean values.  You can also set custom renderers/editors, as Devon pointed out, but you'll still want to store Boolean values instead of JCheckBoxes in that column.